# Can you identify a rose for me?

Tags: roses

Can anyone help me identify this rose, it was a gift from my mum, but unfortunately it died during a move. I live in London Ontario. The rose was a bush and had glossy leaves. Zone 5 Hardy.

[image][image][image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is one ID.  [Carefree Delight Shrub Rose](http://www.rose-gardening-made-easy.com/images/xcarefreedelight.jpg.pagespeed.ic.cHjxd29akt.jpg)  How long ago did your mum give this rose to you?  Was it a new rose or from her garden?  These make spectacular informal hedges when planted en mass.  Roses are extremely tough to ID as there are so many of them!  Bamboo knows her way around Rose ID! She'll be by shortly...I noticed that your shrub pink color is not uniform; some darker pink/salmon some very light.  [Redcoat shrub rose](http://images.mooseyscountrygarden.com/roses/redcoat-shrub-rose.jpg)

Comment: My mum bought it for me at a garden centre in 2012. I tried contacting the garden centre but they're not sure. They gave me some names but none of them fit. The closest I've seen is Osoeasy mango salsa.

Comment: Yes, it was a very unusual rose. Salmon pink with the yellowy peach centre.

Comment: Yummy name!  Can you find something closer to your rose?  What is your shrub's height.  Get the mulch away from the stem and graph during the growing season...For winter, pile  mulch back up over the graph.  So whatever rose you get you won't lose it...Did you see the pics I sent?  Not even close?

Comment: Hi Stormy, thanks for the tips, unfortunately the ones you suggested aren't close. But I shall keep looking